# Please explain why this code has negation of (val) while checking text in input of form in react is less than a particular (len)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, weblogic, react-redux-form

```
const maxLength= (len)=> (val)=> !(val) || (val.length<=len);
```

this is working perfectly fine when I'm calling it like:-

```
<Errors className="text-danger" model=".lastname"
                                    show="touched"
                                    messages={{maxLength: 'Must be 15 characters or less '}}
```

/>

Can you please explain why we are having negation of (val) and constructing this logic with bitwise OR?
I'll be thankful for your quick and convincing explanation!!!!

Just a reminder the code is working completely fine
just wanna know the logic behind it.

Comment: It's not *bitwise* OR, it's the short-circuiting logical OR. `!(val)` means `val` is `null`, `undefined`, the empty string, `0`, `NaN`, or `false`.

Comment: `=>` indicates an arrow function, and `<=` is 'less than or equal to'. Neither are bitwise operators